# Memory leak line

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, memory-leaks

I've seen quite a few questions regarding memory leaks, however what I need to ask is really simple and I'm rather new, so a lot of the explanations are confusing to me (so pardon me for asking this basic question). I have this line of code that I was given to use:

#if defined(DEBUG) | defined (_DEBUG)
_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_OF | CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_OF);
However, on the second line with the _CRTSetDbgFlag, it says there's a use of an undeclared identifier: Use of undeclared identifier '_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_OF' and Use of undeclared identifier 'CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_OF'
#endif

I'm unsure what this means or what I may need to arrange the code to say. Any simple explanations or examples are appreciated. *Note, this is in a main function and is so far the only thing in the main function. Also, as I'm using a Mac computer, I'm unsure if that's why this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a line of code; it should be 3:

```
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined (_DEBUG)
_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_OF | CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_OF);
#endif
```

EDIT: This question changed several times after I answered it and in its current state the issue is a missing include file:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that, however the error is still present unfortunately. Any idea as to why this might be?

Comment: @FeeFae Google for "_CrtSetDbgFlag" and you will hit [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdbgflag?view=vs-2019) for that function and you will see that you need to `#include <crtdbg.h>`.

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I'm sorry, this is all still new and I get lost in the docs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a required header. The mentioned identifiers should be defined in `<crtdbg.h>` which you need to include before using it via:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
```